# resolving GitHub repository environment secrets

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm building a deployment for a Django App from GitHub using actions.  I would like to store secrets at the repository environments and reference them in YAML.  I have two environments TEST and PRODUCTION each have the same secrets defined.

```
- uses: Azure/get-keyvault-secret@v1
  with:
    keyvault: ${{ secrets.KEY_VAULT_NAME }} # Set the name of the KEY VAULT in Azure portal from GITHUB secrets
    secrets: ${{ secrets.KEY_VAULT_SECRET }} # comma separated list of secret keys to fetch from key vault
  id: myGetSecretAction # ID for secrets that you will reference
```

Do I need to switch the environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access environment secrets from a Github workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66521958/how-to-access-environment-secrets-from-a-github-workflow)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment:

environment: Production