# How to pass secrets from GitHub Actions to python environ variables?

Tags: python, environment-variables, github-actions, github-secret

To run `pytest` within GitHub Actions, I have to pass some `secrets` for Python running environ.
e.g.,

```
  - name: Test env vars for python
    run: python -c 'import os;print(os.environ)'
    env:
      TEST_ENV: 'hello world'
      TEST_SECRET: ${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }}
```

However, the output is as follows,

```
environ({
'TEST_ENV': 'hello world',
'TEST_SECRET':'',
...})
```

It seems not working due to [GitHub's redaction](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/security-hardening-for-github-actions#using-secrets).

Based on @raspiduino 's answer, I did more explore on both options to import env vars.

```
name: python

on: push

jobs:
  test_env:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
        
    - name: Test env vars for python
      run: python -c 'import os;print(os.environ)'
      env:
        ENV_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ENV_SECRET }} 
        REPO_SECRET: ${{ secrets.REPO_SECRET }} 
    
    - name: Test inline env vars for python
      run: ENV_SECRET=${{ secrets.ENV_SECRET }} REPO_SECRET=${{ secrets.REPO_SECRET }} python -c 'import os;print(os.environ)'
```

Basically, both steps are in same outputs. The `REPO_SECRET` can be passed thru but not the `ENV_SECRET`.

[image]

Outputs
[image]

Comment: Secrets are redacted *from output*, meaning your program is seeing it correctly. If you absolutely need to *output* them, try encoding in some way (like base64) to bypass GitHub redaction.

Comment: @iBug Just attached the outputs. They are different from Environment and Repository secrets.

Comment: OK I think I know what's going on. For the time being please stick to repository secrets and stay away from "environment secrets". GitHub's "environment" is not like that of an operating system.

Comment: Hi @northtree, I did something very similar here with secrets if you want to take a look :) 
https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/ritchie-formulas-scheduler-demo/blob/main/.github/workflows/formulas-scheduler-secrets.yml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three types of secrets within GitHub Actions.

1. Organization secrets
2. Repository secrets
3. Environment secrets

To access Environment secrets, you have to [referencing an environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environments#referencing-an-environment) in your job. (Thanks to @riQQ)

[image: Actions secrets]

```
name: python

on: push

jobs:
  test_env:
    environment: TEST_SECRET
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
        
    - name: Test env vars for python
      run: python -c 'import os;print(os.environ)'
      env:
        ENV_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ENV_SECRET }} 
        REPO_SECRET: ${{ secrets.REPO_SECRET }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try the things below:

```
  - name: Test env vars for python
    run: TEST_SECRET=${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }} python -c 'import os;print(os.environ['TEST_SECRET'])
```

This will pass `${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }}` directly as an environment variable to the python process and not share with other processes. Then you can use `os.environ['TEST_SECRET']` to get it.

I have done this [here](https://github.com/raspiduino/raspiduino/blob/main/.github/workflows/minesweeper.yml) and [here](https://github.com/raspiduino/raspiduino/blob/main/minesweeper.py)

Comment: I tried more on both Environment and Repository secrets. Only `Repository secrets` can be passed thru. Had you tried on `Environment secrets`?

Comment: @northtree you need to reference the environment in your job: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66521958/how-to-access-environment-secrets-from-a-github-workflow

Answer (score 0):

An other alternative I use is create a .env file with all the secrets, something like this:

```
      - name: Create .env arquive
        run: |
          echo "MY_TOKEN=${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }}" >> ./.env
```