# GitHub Actions not reading in secrets

Tags: github, github-actions

My public repository is over [here](https://github.com/tkreind/Massif-Visualizer-Docker-novnc).

I can't figure out for the life of me why these secrets aren't being read. I've tried every form of logging in with theses secrets that I could think of as you can see from my commit history. In this most recent few versions I've used a bash if statement to check and see that these variables are indeed empty as you can see from the action output.

I've explored multiple similar issues but they're all at least a year old and don't seem to be having the same problem I am.

As you can see, my secret variables do seem to be setup correctly, and have the correct names/spelling.

[image: Screenshot of secrets]

Comment: Did you try using the env vars that you setup? run: docker login -u $username -p $token

Comment: Yep, works perfect other than the security warning about using -p. Neither -p or --password-stdin works in my action, and I've confirmed via bash in the github action that they aren't being passed in.

Comment: You saved your secrets as `environment secrets`, did you try to save them as `repository secrets`?

I also suggest to try Docker Login Action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/docker-login to authenticate, can be useful depending on your context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access environment secrets from a Github workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66521958/how-to-access-environment-secrets-from-a-github-workflow)

Comment: Yes this does! Thank you all so much, I had them in an environment secret instead of a repository one and wasn't referencing the environment in my workflow. To any readers, my repository now reflects referencing the environment correctly in the workflow.