# How to use Environment secrets in github actions workflow for different env like staging and production

Tags: github, github-actions, github-secret

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Google Auth
    id: auth
    uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
    with:
      ENVIRONMENT: staging
      credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GCP_CREDENTIALS }}'
```

using Environment secrets and not Repository secrets as the key names will be the same just env will be different as key values will differ based on env.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access environment secrets from a Github workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66521958/how-to-access-environment-secrets-from-a-github-workflow)